How to handle NewMail or NewMailEx event in outlook web add-in?
outlook COM add-in can handle 'NewMail' or 'NewMail' event,
but in outlook web add-in, I don't find event.
How to handle  'NewMail' or 'NewMailEx' event in outlook Web add-in?
How to handle  'NewMail' or 'NewMailEx' event in outlook Web add-in?

Outlook event NewMail occurs when one or more new email messages are received in the Inbox and NewMailEx occurs when a new item is received in the Inbox. Unfortunately, both of those events are not available to handle in the Web-based add-ons. The available events list is over there. Please note the list is extending from one level API to another, so my statement is valid only at the time of writing this answer, in the future, they might add the event to supported list.
